# Export unresolved list in RTC as a text document

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, rtc, jazz

I am using RTC with visual studio 2013. After I refreshes changes I get a list of files as unresolved. Is there any way by which I can save/export these file names as a text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to fall back to [RTC CLI (command line interface)](https://jazz.net/library/article/620) for that.

An `lscm status` lists the files which are unresolved:

```
[~/test]$ lscm status
Workspace: (1159) "Workspace1" <-> (1159) "Workspace1"
  Component: (1160) "Comp1"
    Baseline: (1161) 2 "SS1"
    Unresolved:
      -c- /Comp1/111/1.txt
  Component: (1162) "Comp2"
    Baseline: (1163) 2 "SS1"
```

[Since RTC4, you can have that result in json](https://jazz.net/library/article/1031#code) (might be easier to parse/process)
See also "
[Scripting using the Rational Team Concert SCM Command Line Interface](https://jazz.net/library/article/1031)".

The advantage of that approach is, of course, the possibility to parse and redirect the output to a file.

Comment: Actually I am unable to find lscm or lscm batch file. I could find only scm. Why is it that?

Comment: @SudhirSomu : https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?re=1&topic=/com.ibm.team.scm.doc/topics/c_scm_cli.html&scope=null: Rational Team Concert source control command line tools are installed in JazzInstallDir/scmtools/eclipse, where JazzInstallDir is the folder in which Rational Team Concert is installed (for example, C:\Program Files\IBM\TeamConcert on Windows. You should find `lscm` there.

Comment: I am searching only at the same place. SCM is available in the folder but LSCM is not.

Comment: I was able to do it using SCM command. Now after getting unresolved list . Let us say a file named program.cs is modified and when I click on compare it checks with earlier version of program.cs. Is there any way by which I can get location of previous version of program.cs and get it into my system?